# How to measure time taken for sending data from client to server

Tags: c++, performance, http, websocket, latency

I am sending data from the client to a server. I want to **accurately** calculate the time taken for the data to reach the destination. The client and server are on different PCs, so I think it is unwise to use the system time as they are on different systems.

Please advise the **most accurate** method for measuring the time taken for the data to reach the destination.

Comment: Why not use clients and servers systems time? Do you want sub second accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

`close` will block until all data is sent, so if you start time at `write`, and end after `close`, you will have the send time. For UDP, the data will have been transmitted, and for TCP it will have been acked.  If you are sending to a Mars rover, then the time will be round trip, but normally the ack time is small.

```
start_time = someTimeFunc();
char *foo = buf;
while (size) {
    ssize_t sent = send(sock,foo,size,flags);
    if (sent <= 0)
        fail;
    foo += sent;
    size -= sent;
}
close(sock);
end_time = someTimeFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

When an app "sends" data, the data is not actually transmitted right away.  It is put in a queue in the OS kernel, and then control is returned to the app.  The kernel will transmit the queued data in the background on its own time.  There is no way to know when the kernel actually transmits, or how long the data takes to arrive as the destination.  And even then, the data is put into another kernel queue at the receiving end, waiting for the receiving app to extract the data from that queue.

So, the only way to do what you are asking for is to have the receiver explicitly send an acknowledgement back to the sender, specifying *when* the data was actually read by the receiver.  The sender and receiver will have to agree on a time scale, like UTC, and also have their clocks synced to a common source.  However, this will NOT be a true reflection of the *transmission* time, but it will likely be *close* if both sender and receiver are handling their respective socket I/O's in a timely manner.

Comment: Lets say we adopt this approach at which point server should send the ACK back to client? Lets say we maintain both client and server not how can we identify that server has parsed whole request body?

Comment: @quintin the receiver (server) would simply wait to send the ACK back to the sender (client) after it has fully received the complete message.

Comment: Yeah if server is a spring boot app created by me at which point I can say that yes I have received the complete request. I was talking about anything which spring provides? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769170/time-taken-by-client-to-send-complete-data-to-api-server